# Proving a decision prob is in NP

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, theory

I am reading CLRS trying to learn on my own and finding this section hard.

I am trying to solve and don't really have a solution to refer to.

Lets say as Input you have:    `x1, x2, x3, ..., xn       m1, m1, m3, ... mn   M1 and M2`

Then you have to output:`A partition into two disjoint subsets S, T (so the intersection is an empty set) so that the sum of each mk (1<=k<=n) of all elements in S is <= M1 and the sum of each mk (1<=k<=n) of all elements in T is <= M2, so that the total value sum of all (xk's in S) + (xk's in T) is maximized. where (1<=k<=n)`

I am trying to prove that it is in NP.
I came across a similar question when I was going through dynamic programming, believe it was for the knapsack. But this seems a bit more complicated. I've been writing out on scrap paper but seem to be getting no where. This is for personal interest.

Comment: That's not a decision problem, a related decision problem could be "*is there* a partition with sum of mk yada yada and total sum greater than Y". Obviously in NP - given two sets, it's pretty easy to test all the requirements.

Comment: Hmm i see , I suppose i have to convert this "optimization" problem to a decision first?

Comment: Yes. And then it will in this case be easy even to prove that it's NP-Complete, using the obvious connection to knapsack

Comment: I'm kind of lost. This stuff is really not obvious to me haha.  I am just trying to prove its in NP.  Care to Elaborate? Thanks really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does each `xi` either `<= M1` or `<= M2` have to be included in `S` and `T`? What is the significance and/or meaning of the `mk`s? (Far as I can see, `m`s and `x`s can't be but one-to-one.) _If_ it coincides with `value`, the `x`s with `m`s smaller than the smaller `Mj` may go to one subset, those with `m`s between the `M`s go to the other - dual pivot partition/quicksort? Seems to be in P, which is included in NP …

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this as the decision version:

> Is there a partition S, T such that S and T are disjoint, the total weight of S <= M1, the total weight of T <= M2, and the total value of S∪T >= Y?

(I reworded it to "weight" and "value" there to make the connection to knapsack more obvious)

Now, is this in NP?

Yes. There are several ways to show membership of NP, the simplest is probably this way: there is a witness that will let us verify (in polynomial time) that a YES answer was correct. The witness is just the pair S and T. The verification here doesn't need any tricks either, just test all the conditions mentioned in the problem.

It's also NP-Complete because it will solve a knapsack instance. This problem is like having two knapsacks, just make the size of one of them zero and it's back to regular knapsack.

Comment: I see, Interesting. I have a observation/question.  what if you wanted to compute the max total value in poly time in the # of input bits?  If the decision problem you posted up there could be solved in poly time then shouldn't it possible? at least this is what I think.

Comment: @VratislavLudvik **if** you could solve the decision problem in poly time, then yes. But you can't.